# Get Strings from Textbox and put in varible array

Tags: regex, vb.net, winforms

I have some dynamic lines of text in a TextBox

TextBox example:

> Nombre : Maria
>   Nombre : Carlos Manuel
>   Nombre : Antonio
>   Nombre : Ana Gabriela
>   .
>   .
>   .

I need to get the names only into an array.
The names are to the right of the `" : "`

```
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myPattern As New Regex(" : ")
Dim myString As String = TextBox1.Text
myMatches = myPattern.Matches(myString)

Dim successfulMatch As Match
Dim counter As Integer = 0 
Dim names(counter) As String

For Each successfulMatch In myMatches
    counter = counter + 1
    names = TextBox1.Text.Split(" : ").Last
Next
```

I want to put the names into an array

> names(1) = Maria
>   names(2) = Carlos Manuel
>   names(3) = Antonio
>   names(4) = Ana Gabriela
>   .
>   .
>   .

Answer (score 1):

You just need the [TextBox.Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines) collection. This property return an Array of strings representing all the lines of text (sub-strings of text separated by a line feed) contained in a TextBoxBase control.

Find the last `:` char and, from this position, take the text to the end of the string:

```
Dim listOfNames = New List(Of String)

For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
        listOfNames.Add(line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(":") + 1).TrimStart())
    End If
Next
```

Using an array of strings, instead of a `List(Of String)`

```
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines
Dim arrayOfNames(lines.Length - 1) As String

For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lines(i)) Then
        arrayOfNames(i) = lines(i).Substring(lines(i).LastIndexOf(":") + 1).TrimStart()
    End If
Next
```

In case you have to use a RegEx for some reason.
Using the `List(Of String)` seen before to store the results:

```
Dim regx = New Regex(":", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(TextBox1.Text)

For Each match As Match In regx
    Dim position = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, match.Index)
    If position = -1 Then position = TextBox1.Text.Length - 1
    listOfNames.Add(TextBox1.Text.Substring(match.Index + 1, position - match.Index).Trim())
Next
```

One-line LINQ version (it returns the well-known `List(Of String)`).
Use `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()` to return an array of strings.
Neither of them to return an `IEnumerable(Of String)`:

```
Dim result = TextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(line) line.Split(":"c)(1).TrimStart()).ToList()
```

Comment: Upvote for complete answer but please don't use l and 1 in the same line of code. As you can see the default font in code boxes is a very similar representation of the a 1 and the l. Old eyes. :-( I am still learning to interpret those chained methods and almost missed the (1)

Comment: @Mary Sorry for compromising your sight. Fixed (I hope).

Comment: Thank you. Still healing from cataract surgery.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function which returns an `IEnumerable(Of String)`

```
Private Function getNombres(text As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return text.
        Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
        Select(Function(l) l.Split(":"c)(1).TrimStart())
End Function
```

call it

```
Dim nombres = getNombres(TextBox1.Text)
```

if you really need it in an array, you can convert it into one

```
Dim nombres = getNombres(TextBox1.Text).ToArray()
```

Note: when indexing the data, you will start with index = 0, contrary to what you asked for in your question. VB6 collections started at 1; .NET collections start at 0.